# C# How do you set the size of a global array on startup?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a few global arrays that I use in multiple classes, which have all been given the same size, at the moment I have hard coded all of their sizes, I read that because C# may not initialise the variables in the order they're written, you can't have a variable to set all of their sizes, is there a way to have a variable that will set all of their sizes?

What I have:

```
public static Object[,] stocksObject = new Object[5,5];
public static double[] stocks = new double[5]; //array holding the stocks (prices)
```

What I want:

```
private int arraySize = 5;
public static Object[,] stocksObject = new Object[arraySize,arraySize];
public static double[] stocks = new double[arraySize]; //array holding the stocks (prices)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you have to make `arraySize` a constant (or static, but prefer constant here). Only then you are allowed to reference it.

```
private const int arraySize = 5;
```

The other fields are static, so you can't use an instance member to initialize them. And for the 'why const and not static': you don't want someone to change the value after the array has been initialized. If your logic depends on that variable, you might end up with buggy code.

Comment: That's not the correct C# naming convention for constants, so strange that you mention it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's the Java naming convention (and it's ugly imho) C# recommends PascalCase for (public) constants. For private constants I think it's camelCase, but it doesn't really matter I guess.

Comment: I'm referring to this now: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397677.aspx

Comment: Okay, lets keep it this way ;)